# SQL Server 2000 - Null for double precision

Tags: java, sql-server-2000, junit4

I have created a test table with the data type double precision

```
   String sql = "create table doub1 (value double precision)";

   fCursor.execute(sql);

   sql = "insert into doub1 values(null)";
   fCursor.parse(sql);
   fCursor.execute();
   fSession.commit();
   sql = "select value from doub1";
   fCursor.executeQuery(sql);
```

When I execute this in the Query Analyzer my output is null.
This is given as

> When query results are viewed in SQL Query Analyzer, null values are
>   shown as (null) in the result set.

in the following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196106(v=sql.80).aspx

But when I execute the above through Junit, My output is 0.0.

I would like to know why this is happening.
Could someone provide a clarification on this please?

Thanks

Comment: are you retrieving the data as double or `Double`?

Comment: retrieving as Double                                                                                                                                  public Double getDouble(int col) throws DBException {
        Object value = fCurrentRow.get(col);
        if (value instanceof Number) {
            return ((Number)value).doubleValue();
        }
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return Double.parseDouble(value.toString().trim());
    }